# Shell script handling variables

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm passing 2 variables from php to my .sh file using

```
exec("./script.sh $a $b");
```

I can echo these values inside .sh  but I can't use these variables anywhere else. for ex. it's not creatiing the database $1 and folder $2.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -p'password' currentdb > /home/admin/mydb.sql
echo "create database" $1 | mysql -u root -p'password'
mysql -u root -p'password' $1 < /home/admin/mydb.sql

mkdir /var/www/instance/$2
chmod -R 777 /var/www/instance/$2

cp -r /var/www/instance/current/* /var/www/instance/$2/
cd /var/www/instance/$2/
sed -i 's/currentdb/$1/g' configuration.php
```

where am I doing it wrong? please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know what is wrong with script as such, but I suggest double quoting `$1` and  `$2`.

Comment: Also you are using a relative path in `exec("./script.sh $a $b");` Are you sure the script is in the same folder as the php file?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder.  But variables are empty.

Comment: Can you run script.sh manually?

Comment: Yes I can run it perfectly by passing the values manually. But I want to pass the values using php form.

Comment: Then I would try adding "set -x" to the bash script and log the output when called from php.

Comment: sjsam  was right. double quoting $1 and $2 worked.

Comment: I hope @sjsam creates an answer for you to accept, so this can show up as Answered :-)